# Best way to have UITableView within another table?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a grouped UITableView in class A and if you select a row in section 0, I want it to open up to another UITableView. In the first view, I have a lot of other methods and buttons and custom designed stuff, so I don't want to create another XIB for the other table view since I'll have to copy over all the methods and custom designed stuff. I was thinking creating another XIB, but subclassing the class under the original class A this way I can use the methods of class A without having to redefine them again in the new class. But I'm having problems with this. Is there a better way? Can I have two table views in one XIB, and just hide one till the other is called up? But that seems a little messy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply try subclassing the existing viewcontroller it will have the same info for the selected row, hence it would have to grow exponentially in order to make display the right UITableView.

If your concern is redefining methods, then simply create a class that will hold those particular methods and include it in the UITableViewControllers that will be using them, that way you will only define it once. This way you can simply create a new UITableViewController and push it into a navigation controller everytime you select a given cell.

As an alternative of showing all options within one UITableView you can try the following: you can probably try adding a UIScrollView inside the UITableViewCell. I would make it scroll horizontally while keeping the UITableView scroll vertically.